# Як правильно перекласти з російкої "втачной пояс"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

[image]

Перекладаю як "вшитий пояс". Як думаєте?

Comment: Було б добре, якби Ви пояснили, що таке «втачивание». Я розумію, що Ваше питання приблизно про те і було, який українським словом це поняття найкраще передати — але хоч приблизно пояснити зміст. Бо не всі тут володіють швацькою термінологією.

Comment: втачивание
ВТАЧА́ТЬ, -а́ю, -а́ешь; вта́чанный; сов., что. Тачая, вшить. В. рукава.   Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

Comment: @ХристинаГап'як, коментарі до запитання ставлять на меті покращення запитання. Тому, будь ласка, усі уточнення треба писати не окремим коментарем, а редагувати [edit] запитання і вписувати уточнення туди.

Answer (score 2):

Я доволі погано знаюся на швацькій термінології. Але на основі оцих визначень російських слів:

> <sub>[Втачно́й](//dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/149986) (прил.) — вшитый посредством втачивания (Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000).</sub>
>   <sub>[Втачивание деталей одежды](//fashion.academic.ru/461) — стандартизированный технологический термин, обозначающий ниточное соединение деталей по овальному контуру (например, втачивание рукавов в проймы, втачивание воротника) (Терминологический словарь одежды. Орленко Л. В., 1996).</sub>

— і оцих перекладів російських слів (у словнику The Russian-Ukrainian Dictionary на сайті ABBYY Lingvo Live):

> <sub>[Вта́чивание](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) — ушива́ння.</sub>
>   <sub>[Вта́чивать](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) *спец.*; *несов.*; *сов.* - втача́ть — ушива́ти, уши́ти и *мног.* повшива́ти.</sub>

— можу запропонувати такі варіанти:

- «**Вшивни́й по́яс**».

  «Словник української мови» в 20 томах:

  > [ВШИВНИ́Й (УШИВНИ́Й)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17106&page=573), а́, е́. Який вшивається в що-небудь. *Модними у цьому сезоні будуть жіночі сукні з вшивними рукавами, облямованими хутром* (з газ.).
- «**По́яс-вши́вка**».

  «Словник української мови» в 20 томах:

  > [ВШИ́ВКА (УШИ́ВКА)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17105&page=573), и, *ж*. Те, що вшите; вставка. *Коли стих бій.., на рейках знайшли серед трупів двох, одягнутих у піджачки з плисовими вшивками на рукавах, якими німці мітили полонених* (П. Панч); *Виробники офіційних сувенірів дуже серйозно ставляться до захисту продукції від підробок. Так, кожен такий предмет матиме на собі своєрідну “акцизну марку” – голографічний знак захисту, а футболки і кепки – спеціальну вшивку з логотипом конкурсу* (із журн.).
- «**Вши́тий по́яс**».

  «Словник української мови» в 20 томах:

  > [ВШИ́ТИЙ¹ (УШИ́ТИЙ)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17113&page=574), а, е. Дієпр. пас. до вши́ти¹. *На погонах, вшитих у плечі фуфайки, товстим шаром осіла сіра пилюка* (О. Гончар); <…>
  >
  > ---
  >
  > [ВШИВА́ТИ¹ (УШИВА́ТИ)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17101&page=573), а́ю, а́єш, *недок.*, ВШИ́ТИ (УШИ́ТИ), вши́ю, вши́єш, *док.*, *що, у що*. Зашивати що-небудь у середину чогось; пришивати, вставляючи в що-небудь. <…>

  Недоліком цього варіанту є те, що це пасивний дієприкметник минулого часу доконаного дієслова, тобто позначає пояс, уже вшитий (а не готовий для вшивання абощо).

<sub>Іще додатково знайшов такі цікаві переклади російського дієслова «вта́чивать»/«втача́ть»: *вштуко́вувати*, *вштукува́ти*, *приштуко́вувати*, *приштукува́ти* («Російсько-український академічний словник» А. Кримського та С. Єфремова 1924—1933 років і «Словарь росийсько-український» М. Уманця і А. Спілки 1893–1898 років на [R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=rusb)) — але не знаю, як створити з них прикметник/дієприкметник.</sub>